# Visual studio 2008 project level settings

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to export settings for C# formatting at a project level so that we can put the settings file on a repository and everyone can use it without affecting other projects that are using different formatting styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For Visual Studio C# environment
  settings, you can **Export** them
  from Tools->Import and Export
  Settings->Export Selected Environment
  Settings, then save the file.

  You can store this file somewhere on
  the network, in Source Safe or TFS.

  Then the other devs who want to use
  those settings will **Import** them
  Tools->Import and Export
  Settings->Import Select Environment
  Settings, select the file and press
  import.
- It can also be loaded from command
  line, or a **desktop shortcut**

  ```
   Devenv.exe "C:\MySolution.sln" /ResetSettings "C:\MySettings.vssettings"
  ```
- Consider the **Code Analysis Policy
  Editor** in [Check-In Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181281(VS.80).aspx).
- If what you are looking for is not
  built in, you might need to look for
  an **Add-in**, [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=add-in%20visual%20studio&ac=1) has over 500
  of them. If you don't find it, you
  might have to make [Make](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esk3eey8(VS.71).aspx)  one.
- Another possible solution is to bring
  the teams together in a **coding
  standard meeting** where they can agree
  on a [common coding standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(v=VS.71).aspx),
  then use a tool like
  [CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx) to do the **code
  refactoring automatically**.

Comment: That will change the settings of visual studio and not just for that project though.  If you try to open a different project it will still be using the settings that you imported.  Is there a way to have it at a project level so that it only affects that one project?

Comment: by Team Project then, and the settings are Visual Studio environment settings, right? Why does each of your Team Projects need to have their own environment settings?

Comment: Some of the developers work on different projects and each project has different developers working on it. Sometimes each team has their own set of coding standards that they want to use.  So we don't want to keep changing the settings every time we decide to work on a different project.